# How to improve basement stairwell drainage?

Tags: water, drainage, exterior

So we have a basement walkout door. There is a stairwell that leads down to it. There’s a big landing but this is the drain in the middle of it. It has a tendency to get clogged with debris from trees etc that float in. I popped off the metal grate which was easy enough but now I don’t know what is going on. There appears to be a 4 inch rough cut vertical pipe in which I can see some sitting water about a foot down. The existing metal fixture appears to be just concreted in place. I had got the atrium drain in hopes of attaching it but that doesn’t seem to be an option. Should I just get a 3x3 section of hardware cloth or a entrance floor mat with holes and just put that on top?[image: drain]

Answer (score 0):

I watched a YouTube video that had a great idea to help.  Put down 2 grill grates over the drain, then a heavy duty rubber mat with holes on top of that. This allows the water to drain while keeping debris from clogging it up.

Answer (score 0):

Consider getting a drain augur (they're available for rent if you don't want to purchase one) and running that down the drain. It's highly likely that this drain is partially clogged due to debris that's small enough to fit between the bars of that metal grill.

Once the drain is cleaned out, some hardware cloth on the inside of the metal grill seems like it would be a good option to keep most non-water things from going down the drain in the future. You'll probably need to pop the gill out on a regular basis to dump the crud out of it. Make sure you dump it into the garbage or yard, not right there at the bottom of the stairs or it'll end up right there in the grill again next time it rains.

Answer (score 0):

Drains like that (speaking from first hand experience) are disasters waiting to happen.  All it takes is for a big leaf or two to lay down over the grates to block the flow of water.  Then the stairwell fills up until it flows over the threshold into the basement.

Here's what did.  I found a short piece of PVC pipe that would fit down into the existing pipe.  Think it was 1-1/2" diameter.  Then I glued a 1-1/2" to 2" transition to one end.  This keeps the PVC pipe from falling down into the drain.

I drilled a bunch holes around the top of the 1-1/2" pipe and around the transition.  When the pipe+transition is placed into the existing drain, these holes allow any water in the well to flow down into the PVC pipe and down into the drain.  The multiple holes means that it's unlikely that all of them will become clogged or blocked by debris.

You can then cap of the top of the 2" transition with some wire mesh or a 2" cap, with holes drilled in it.

Comment: This is, essentially, a DIY version of the green atrium drain the OP has in his picture. The big drawback is that (in the OPs case, at least) it's right in the middle of the stair landing which could impede the operation of an out swinging door and is, at a minimum, a tripping hazard.

Comment: @FreeMan - I had considered that, but found that it was too easy to dislodge the atrium drain.